# Ways of formatting an AngularJS directive template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm looking at ways to format templates in AngularJS directives. The most common are:

**Inline:**

```
// Directive.js
app.directive('flipCard', [
  function() {
    return {
      template:
        "<div class='cardslot' ng-class='{\"switch\":shouldFlip}'> \
          <card-side candidate-model='currentCandidate' class='card-a-side'></card-side> \
          <card-side candidate-model='nextCandidate' class='card-b-side'></card-side> \
        </div>"
    };
  }
]);
```

Advantages:

- keeps all directive code in 1 file (cleaner)
- doesn't require an extra file to be loaded at runtime

Disadvantages:

- hard to format, ugly
- no code completion, no tag highlighting
- nesting " in ' in " and ' might become complicated

**External**

```
// Directive.js
app.directive('directive', [
  function() {
    return {
      templateUrl: '/views/partials/directive.html'
    };
  }
]);

// Directive.html
<div class="cardslot" ng-class="{'switch':shouldFlip}">
  <card-side candidate-model="currentCandidate" class="card-a-side"></card-side>
  <card-side candidate-model="nextCandidate" class="card-b-side"></card-side>
</div>
```

Advantages:

- cleaner formatting
- code highlighting & code completion
- cleans up directive code by removing html tags and keeping the javascript

Disadvantages:

- needs an extra file per directive (while coding & at runtime)
- might feel as overkill with smaller template code

That's some in column A and some in column B. So how do I choose between them? When is inline formatting preferable and when is external formatting preferable?

More generally, should I be considering other methods?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks a real problem, and is more suitable in the library's documentation.

Comment: [Meta discussion about this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225943/close-reason-off-topic-as-asks-for-best-practices-or-ways-of-usage)

Answer (score 1):

In my project I do the both methods at the same time ;) :

- development : It's good practice to have a separate file for each templates (with module subfolder if needed) because it's simplier to maintain and for readability.
- runtime/ packaging-build : I use [html2js](https://github.com/karlgoldstein/grunt-html2js) to real-time replace my templateUrl string by the template content.

Verbose code, optimised generated code, less HTTP hits, cached templates, etc ...

Answer (score 1):

There is a third way, which I prefer, to use templateUrl to reference the id of an element within your existing markup. IMHO I think it's more consistent with the declarative approach of Angular

```
<div ng-app="pageModule"
    ng-controller="parentCtrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myTemplate">
        <span ng-click="remove()">{{label}}</span>
    </script>
    <div my-directive></div>
</div>



var pageModule = angular.module('pageModule',[])
.controller('parentCtrl',function($scope) {
})
.directive('myDirective',function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        templateUrl : 'myTemplate'
```

Comment: but in the end it depends, sometimes this approach I suggest is not appropriate. I think all ways you suggest have their place, but I would in general avoid putting the markup directly into the directive. It makes it very difficult to read for non javascript programmers